# asp.net core: IApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping isn't triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I saw a few articles about IApplicationLifetime and the way I can trigger execution when application starts and stops but I probably miss something because it is just not triggered.
Here is my workaround:
I opened a project template Container Application for kubernetes, asp.net core 2.2

Program.cs looks as it was created:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Kubernetes1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs looks as following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Kubernetes1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            //var appLifetime = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IApplicationLifetime>();
            appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("ApplicationStopping called"));
            appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("ApplicationStopped called"));
            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("AAA");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

All I wanted to do here is running the app in cmd, then stop it and see 2 lines printed in console:

1. ApplicationStopping called
2. ApplicationStopped called
   I didn't manage to make it happen.
   Any ideas?

Comment: How do you stop your program when check the output?

Comment: in a different cmd window I type: 
`Get-Process -Name *dotnet* | Stop-Process`

Comment: Try `cntrl+c` in the same window.

Comment: Thanks! indeed it was the issue. did'nt know that stop-process isn't a gracefully stopping

Answer (score 4):

> in a different cmd window I type: `Get-Process -Name *dotnet* | Stop-Process`

`Stop-Process` will *kill* the process, skipping any graceful shutdown behavior an application might have.

When the `IApplicationLifetime` talks about the application stopping, then it refers to the application being gracefully shut down. There are a few ways to trigger this, depending on how the application is starting:

- When the application is running in the console: <kbd>CTRL + C</kbd>. For example when running through `dotnet run` or running the compiled executable directly.
- When the application is running in IIS: Stopping the website or the application pool.
- When the application is running as a Windows Service: Stopping the service.

Comment: I am in a similar situation as above, but it won't work.  I'm running in IIS Express.  I use the task tray to "Stop Site", but my application stopping event is never hit.  Does this not work with IIS Express perhaps?

Comment: I will had that in debug the "Stop debugging" doesn't trigger the graceful stop, you should follow the first case with CTRL + C in console.